# PowerShell: How to add XmlElement to a non-root element

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm having trouble adding an XmlElement to a non-root element in PowerShell.

Basically, given this xml:

```
<clubs>
        <club name="boca" position="1">
                <field>bombonera</field>
                <field>bombonerita</field>
        </club>
        <club name="racing" position="19">
                <field>cilindro</field>
        </club>
</clubs>
```

I want to achieve this

```
<clubs> 
        <club name="boca" position="1"> 
                <field>bombonera</field> 
                <field>bombonerita</field> 
        </club> 
        <club name="racing" position="19"> 
                <field>cilindro</field> 
        </club> 
        <club name="barracas" />
</clubs>
```

I create an element,

```
$new = $clubs.CreateElement("barracas")
```

When I try to add this element to a non-root node i.e.

```
$clubs.clubs.club += $new
```

I get

```
Cannot set "club" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using the **AppendChild** method on the appropriate element. There are alternatives to AppendChild as described in [Create New Nodes in the DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k44daxya.aspx) which allow you more control of the location in the DOM tree.

```
$club = $xml.CreateElement('club')
$club.SetAttribute('name','barracas')
$xml.clubs.AppendChild($club)
```