# Powershell Add XmlElement As the first child

Tags: powershell

This is a variation of the following question at:

[PowerShell: How to add XmlElement to a non-root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041489/powershell-how-to-add-xmlelement-to-a-non-root-element)

So I'll run with the data the OP used in that question.  Given the following XML snippet:

```
<clubs>
</clubs>
```

or

```
<clubs />
```

What I'm trying to do is add the first element so that my resulting XML looks like:

```
<clubs>
    <club name="barracas" rating="awesome" />
</clubs>
```

So far, I have tried:  Append, InsertAfter (although I'm not 100% sure how that works)

```
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement("club")
$newNode.SetAttribute("name", "barracas");
$newnode.SetAttribute("rating", "awesome");
$xml.clubs.Append($newnode)
$xml.clubs.InsertAfter($newNode, $xml.clubs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$xml.clubs` is a string in this scenario and not an `XmlNode`.  Try this instead:

```
$xml.FirstChild.AppendChild($newNode)
```

Of course, if the element is further down the tree, you'd probably be better off using the `SelectSingleNode()` method

Comment: hmmm, this didn't work for me.  I ended up doing a search and replace which appeared to solve my problem.

Comment: I had to do something similar on another script and it turns out that this *did* work.  Unfortunately, as a PS noob, I admit I didn't see the wisdom of your solution when you first posted this.  Cheers.

Comment: I am not sure what the author was looking for 10 years ago, but I was looking for "PrependChild" as shown in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/create-new-nodes-in-the-dom?redirectedfrom=MSDN